# Error running DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am working on this Oracle DB version `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production`

I have this String `@IBERIA,P30L0X00054A4,2017-12-04T06:44:09,4.3803048133850,50.8304405212402` stored in `VARCHAR2`

But running this function:

```
lv_tab_length   BINARY_INTEGER;
lt_array   DBMS_UTILITY.lname_array;
p_imei VARCHAR2(50);
UTC_time VARCHAR2(50);
asset_latitude  VARCHAR2(20);   
asset_longitude VARCHAR2(20);

DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE( list => p_msg
                              , tablen => lv_tab_length
                              , tab => lt_array
                              );

 p_imei          :=  lt_array( 1 );     
 UTC_time        :=  lt_array( 2 );    
 asset_latitude  :=  lt_array( 3 );
 asset_longitude :=  lt_array( 4 );
```

I got this error:

```
ORA-20001: comma-separated list invalid near 2
```

Comment: This function is for splitting "comma-delimited list of names", Names have to follow Schema Object Naming Rules. It's not normal list of strings.

Comment: Look at the documentation about the details of the parameter. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_util.htm#ARPLS73224

Comment: Do NOT use this function for splitting comma-separated strings! I have seen this so-called "advice" in a few places; it is BAD ADVICE. As the others have already said: this function has a different purpose; and using it the way you are will sometimes cause errors, if not worse (splitting the strings, removing "invalid" characters, saving what is left - with NO WARNING to you or to anyone else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v_array apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
v_array := apex_util.string_to_table(p_msg, ',');

p_imei          :=  v_array( 1 );     
UTC_time        :=  v_array( 2 );    
asset_latitude  :=  v_array( 3 );
asset_longitude :=  v_array( 4 );
```